# To use public computer, is it reasonable to assume one is in the clear net even if one use Tails?

Tags: anonymity, tails

Is it reasonable to assume communication on a public computer can not be made anonymized even with utilization of Tails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Lunar's answer is accurate, it is restricted to IT stuff, and you shouldn't overlook non-IT stuff, the most obvious is CCTV and hidden cams, but also just people looking over your shoulder. Public computers are, after all, in the public..

Answer (score 2):

Unless hardware or very low level software monitoring solutions have been deployed, a public computer booted with Tails will properly protect the privacy of its users.

Users should eventually [disable MAC address spoofing](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/startup_options/mac_spoofing/) as it might raise suspicions from the local network administrator or prevent the computer to access the network entirely.